# Нужна ли запятая после слова «возможно»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

*И многие из них жили здесь поколениями, возможно, с драгоценными семейными реликвиями, в панике брошенными под натиском потопа.*

Думаю, здесь это слово является именно вводным, но всё же запятую после него ставить совсем не хочется. Слышал давно, что вводные слова, находящиеся в начале конструкций по типу п/о, не выделяются запятой, но здесь вроде как не такой случай (или я ошибаюсь и как раз такой).

В общем, помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правы, есть такое правило. Из справочника Розенталя:

> [**4.**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122) Если вводное слово (сочетание) стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения), то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно не отделяется: <...> *Спокойно потягивает трубочку смуглый, коренастый капитан, **по-видимому итальянец или грек*** (Кат.); <...> *Вечер сегодня будет по-осеннему серый, **наверно ненастный***; <...> *Он вспоминал эти слова, **возможно слышанные в детстве***...

Упростим предложение:
*И многие из них жили здесь поколениями, с реликвиями...*

1. Если мы отнесем вводное слово к *поколениям*, то предложение будет иметь такой вид:
   *И многие из них жили здесь **поколениями возможно,** с реликвиями...*
2. Если к *реликвиям*, то такой:
   *И многие из них жили здесь поколениями, **возможно с реликвиями**...*

Опускание одной запятой позволяет понять, к какому же слову относится вводное.
Думаю, что по смыслу это второе предложение, поэтому запятая после "возможно" не ставится.

Answer (score 0):

1. Лучше обособить **вводное слово:**

*И многие из них жили здесь поколениями, /**возможно, /** с драгоценными семейными **релИквиями**, // в панике брошенными под натиском потопа.*

Можно по смыслу определить, что вводное слово  не относится к первой части, а находится **в середине** предложения, **сравнить:** *И многие из них жили здесь поколениями / **с драгоценными семейными релИквиями,** в панике брошенными под натиском потопа.*

В то же время решение зависит **от контекста** (такой вариант подходит, если тема драгоценных реликвий уже **была названа**, а здесь она логически **выделена** ударением).

2. В других случаях возможно обособление с помощью **тире всего оборота** (ударение на "поколениями"):

*И многие из них жили здесь **поколЕниями** — **возможно,** с драгоценными семейными реликвиями, в панике брошенными под натиском потопа.*